# pyspark udf regex_extract - "'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'"

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am experiencing a very odd problem in pyspark.. I am using regex to extract a unixtimestamp from an lengthy datetime string (stored string is unsuitable for direct conversion). This works fine when writing it into a withColumn function:

```
r= "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\.([0-9]*)"
latencyhops.select('time') \
.withColumn('TimeSec',f.unix_timestamp(f.regexp_extract('time', r, 1))) \
.show(5,False)

+---------------------------+----------+
|time                       |TimeSec   |
+---------------------------+----------+
|2018-01-22 14:39:00.0743640|1516631940|
|2018-01-23 05:47:34.2797780|1516686454|
|2018-01-23 05:47:34.2797780|1516686454|
|2018-01-23 05:47:34.2797780|1516686454|
|2018-01-24 08:06:29.2989410|1516781189|
```

However when running via a UDF it fails:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def timeConversion (time):
    return f.unix_timestamp(f.regexp_extract(time, "([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-
[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\.([0-9]*)", 1))
to_nano =udf(timeConversion, IntegerType())

latencyhops.select('time') \
.withColumn('TimeSec',to_nano('time', r, 1)) \
.show(5,False)
```

With:

```
..../pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 1521, in regexp_extract
    jc = sc._jvm.functions.regexp_extract(_to_java_column(str), pattern, idx)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

As far as I can tell these should be doing exactly the same thing. I have tried multiple variants of defining the UDF (lambda expressions etc) but always hit the same error. Does anyone have advice?

Thanks

Comment: in the code you need to call the udf and not the function. You are calling timeConversion('time', r, 1)) wheras it should be to_nano

Comment: Also, `unix_timestamp` and other pyspark functions work on column level, they won't work inside a udf.

Comment: @pratiklodha - sorry that was an artifact of changing around function names. I have tried with to_nano.

Comment: @mkaran - sounds like that is the reason why! Thanks, I was not aware

Comment: @AMcNall glad you solved it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mkaran pointed out, many pyspark functions only work on the column level so are unsuitable for UDF use. Went with a .withColumn solution which worked.